# When I go on meta chat, I am logged in as the wrong user (but meta and SO chat work fine)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, meta, login

When I go on meta chat, I am logged in as another SE user named "Jeff Atwood" I created a long time ago, which is dead now. I am unable to find a link to the "Jeff Atwood" named user through search, sorry. SO and other chats work fine (I am logged in the correct user) and so does meta.

I though maybe it was something to do with cookies/cache, so I opened a new icognito window in Chrome(ium actually) and logged in with my SE account and the problem persisted.

<sup>*the ghost of the account is coming back to haunt me*</sup>

*Update*: in another browser (Rekonq), everything was working normally, except that the name on the top was "Jeff Atwood". But when I joined a room, I was able to enter and my name and image were displayed. When I cleared the cache of the browser and again loaded meta.chat.SO, it showed my name. I guess this is a cache issue.

Comment: FWIW, yep, I saw that happen indeed. With a random Gravatar icon.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Jeff Atwood is your sockpuppet?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar no, but it's not Latin A but Cryllic A. I've seen you on the TDWTF forums °͜°.

Comment: @ram how can you be sure one of us isn't lying? Aha! Your cunning attempt at unmasking me is foiled! *whoosh*

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I was temporarily suspended because I was under 13, because I still wanted to have an account, I created an account and named it "Jeff Atwood" out of some rageous thinking.

Comment: Can you link at the chat user you are impersonating? Can you try on a different browser?

Comment: @Sklivvz Weird, in Chromium it's working perfectly now, but in Rekonq (that's the only other browser that's installed; it uses Qt WebKit), the username on top shows up as "Jeff Atwood"; it's linked to http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/236473/jeff-twood . When I click it it goes to my chat.meta.SO user (the user id is the same as mine but the name at the end of the link is wrong). Also, I am able to access the rooms and in the rooms it shows my image and username.
Maybe it's something to do with the cache, I hadn't cleared that.

Comment: Ok, I'll mark this as no-repro.

Comment: @Sklivvz I cleared the cache in Rekonq, and now my name on top shows up as my name. I guess this is a cache issue.

Comment: Shall I answer this question with "It seems to be a cache issue..."?

Comment: Be my guest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried again, the problem did not exist in Chromium, but in another browser Rekonq it existed. When I cleared the cache of Rekonq and again loaded meta.chat.SO, it showed my name.

I guess this is a cache issue.

Comment: When it comes to Jeff Atwood, it's _always_ a cache issue.

Comment: @TimPost Jeff Atwood is annoyingly *persistent* :)